# Настройки файла httpd.conf для отображения .htaccess

Tags: php, apache

День добрый. Я недавно изучаю PHP и т.д., поэтому может чего то не так понял в предыдущих ответах.

Суть вопроса, как я уже прочитал в других ответах, для того чтобы был виден файл с расширением .htaccess (в корневой папке проекта) нужно в конфигурационном файле Apache - httpd.conf ("C:\OSPanel\modules\http\Apache-PHP-7.2-x64\conf\httpd.conf") поменять некоторые параметры, а именно: AllowOverride None заменить на AllowOverride All и сохранить.

При этом у меня в httpd.conf есть также (AccessFileName .htaccess). 
Но проблема в том что после изменения всех этих настроек, сохранения файла, и перезапуска сервера, программа заново генерирует данный файл т.е. создает httpd.conf с базовыми настройками, т.е. AllowOverride None. Как сделать так чтобы мои настройки не менялись. Спасибо.

Comment: У вас видимо стоит денвер или подобный пакет?

Comment: В качестве сервера установил пакет OSpanel (open server). В качестве IDE - PHPStorn (jetbrains)

Comment: Настройки вносите через OSPanel или в ручную в файлы?(второе - может не работать по причине того что OSPanel будет их перезаписывать своими настройками)

Comment: да, вручную. я просто открываю данный файл через PHPstorm.

Comment: а как его изменить через OSpanel?

Comment: Почитайте документацию к серверу, скорей всего ответ там.

Comment: Все просто, заходишь в панель управления open server и вот тут откроется конфиг текущей конфигурации https://yadi.sk/i/tSLCM7-H8Hz4uA

Comment: благодарю всех за ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Через редактирование файлов напрямую ничего не сохранится, всегда редактируйте через панель OPServer:

Настройки=>Дополнительно=>Конфигурация=>Apache-PHP-7.2-x64